# Compiling tools using pcl fails during linking

Tags: pcl, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently I'm trying to update our code base to be used with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and indigo. When building a package which uses PCL I hit this issue:

> /usr/bin/ld:
> /usr/local/lib/libqhull.a(mem.c.o)(.debug_info+0x701):
> unresolvable R_X86_64_64 relocation
> against symbol `qhmem'   /usr/bin/ld:
> final link failed: Nonrepresentable
> section on output   collect2: error:
> ld returned 1 exit status

It seems there is something fatally broken/mixed up with headers and the pre-compiled 32/64 bit libraries. Reinstalling the libqhull packages won't resolve this issue. So, has anybody an idea how to solve this?

Best wishes,
Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173821/compiling-tools-using-pcl-fails-during-linking/) by [a_stumpf](https://answers.ros.org/users/18251/a_stumpf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Deleting /usr/local/lib/libqhull.a and doing

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libopencv-dev libpcl-1.7-all-dev ros-indigo-pcl-ros
```

clean your project and rebuild it.

Credit: David Conner

---

Originally posted by [romay](https://answers.ros.org/users/20402/romay/) with karma: 56 on 2015-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0